# I cannot send a mail in mule

Tags: mule

I get that error message when I try to execute my muleproject

> "The endpoint is malformed  an cannot be parsed" and this is the endpoint

Here's the code:

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="mymail@gmail.com" password="mypass" 
to="destiny@gmail.com" from="my@gmail.com" responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="SMTP" port="587" subject="the subject"/>
```

where is the mistake??

I have removed the "@gmail.com" from user and the project now is deployed but  it rises this exception

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a      STARTTLS command first. cf12sm8298386wjb.10 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Here is the full stacktrace

```
    INFO  2015-03-26 22:26:00,479 [[domotica2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.email.transformers.ObjectToMimeMessage
INFO  2015-03-26 22:26:00,499 [[domotica2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.2081412619'. Object is: SmtpMessageDispatcher
INFO  2015-03-26 22:26:00,912 [[domotica2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.2081412619'. Object is: SmtpMessageDispatcher
ERROR 2015-03-26 22:26:01,100 [[domotica2].connector.smtp.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://mymail:<password>@smtp.gmail.com, connector=SmtpConnector
{
  name=connector.smtp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=77c233af
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.smtp.mymail.gmail.com.587', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={fromAddress=mymail@gmail.com, toAddresses=destiny@gmail.com, subject=SD}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. md2sm586901wic.19 - gsmtp
 (com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException)
  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport:1829 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://mymail:<password>@smtp.gmail.com, connector=SmtpConnector
{
  name=connector.smtp.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=77c233af
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.smtp.mymail.gmail.com.587', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={fromAddress=mymail@gmail.com, toAddresses=destiny@gmail.com, subject=SD}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. md2sm586901wic.19 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Try removing the "@gmail.com" from the user attribute or using "%40gmail.com" instead. What version of mule are you using?

Comment: Anypoint Studio 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific connector for GMail SMTP named `smtp:gmail-connector`

Here is an example usage:

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="smtpGmailConnector"  bccAddresses="abc@example.com" ccAddresses="bcd@example.com" contentType="foo/bar"
fromAddress="cde@example.com" replyToAddresses="def@example.com"
subject="subject">
  <smtp:header key="foo" value="bar" />
  <smtp:header key="baz" value="boz" />
</smtp:gmail-connector>
```

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SMTP+Transport+Reference#SMTPTransportReference-Connectors (scroll down for the GMail connector example, just above **Endpoints**).

Comment: I've checked the example but..where are  username and password fields?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is what the endpoint should look like removing the "@gmail.com":

`<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="mymail" password="mypass" 
to="destiny@gmail.com" from="my@gmail.com" responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="SMTP" port="587" subject="the subject"/>`

or replacing the @ instead:

`<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="mymail%40gmail.com" password="mypass" 
to="destiny@gmail.com" from="my@gmail.com" responseTimeout="10000" 
doc:name="SMTP" port="587" subject="the subject"/>`

Comment: I have the same problem  i get this error `name='endpoint.smtp.mymail.gmail.com.587', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={fromAddress=mymail@gmail.com, toAddresses=destiny@gmail.com, subject=SD}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: MimeMessage
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999`

Comment: That looks like an issue when the mail is sent. Could you edit the original question to add that new stack trace?

Comment: I have added the full stacktrace on the original question.

Comment: Right, the problem is that gmail requires SSL which means using the ```smtps``` connector. As David Dossot mentions, you can also use the Gmail SMTP connector too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @ and replace it with %40.